# image is not clickable

Tags: html, image, anchor

I have new code on my website and a portion of my image icons are not clickable.  The url shows up so it is reading the a tag but you cannot click the picture.  Any insight would be helpful.

http://staging.pinupgirlclothing.com/retrodresses/lush-dress-swan.html

see shop the look

html layout is:

```
<ul class="box-content">
                <li class="item first">
                <div class="item-info">
        <a href="http://staging.pinupgirlclothing.com/new-items/sp-15252-pk.html" class="product-image"><img src="http://staging.pinupgirlclothing.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/115x150/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/p/sp-15252-pk_01t.jpg" width="115" height="150" alt="Floozy Kiss Lock Purse in Baby Pink Size- 939450" title="Floozy Kiss Lock Purse in Baby Pink Size- 939450" /></a>
    </div>
        </li>
                            <li class="item">
                <div class="item-info">
        <a href="http://staging.pinupgirlclothing.com/new-items/il-hs-bk.html" class="product-image"><img src="http://staging.pinupgirlclothing.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/115x150/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/l/il-hs-bk_01.jpg" width="115" height="150" alt="Vintage Style Sheer Hair Scarf in Black Size- 952104" title="Vintage Style Sheer Hair Scarf in Black Size- 952104" /></a>
    </div>
        </li>
                            <li class="item last">
                <div class="item-info">
        <a href="http://staging.pinupgirlclothing.com/new-items/black-jelly-flats.html" class="product-image"><img src="http://staging.pinupgirlclothing.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/115x150/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/i/fi-032jelly-bk_01_1.jpg" width="115" height="150" alt="Dragonfly Jelly Peeptoe Flats in Black" title="Dragonfly Jelly Peeptoe Flats in Black" /></a>
    </div>
        </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Your code is fine.   The issue has to be somewhere else.   I copied your code in to a jsFiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/Cfsamet/G9EuE/) and it works okay.

Comment: Please correct your javascript code before. Console in your website shows `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input lush-dress-swan.html:1` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined prototype.js:2754`

Comment: Maybe there is no error in the code and this is just a big hidden ad?

Comment: No, look at his site, the html is ok, and there's no iframe or other container in front. I think about a javascript issue, an overload of the click event on the <a>, preventing the link to be followed. I see many javascripts errors : try to correct them.

Comment: It's your zoomlens div.  It's got a z-index of 999, so it's stealing the focus from the image link.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will go through and correct the js first retest, then change the js code for default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This code in main.js is your problem.  Don't preventDefault if you don't want the default behavior (following the link) to be prevented:

```
    $('.product-view a.product-image').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: I see on my page the programmer is using the class attribute in the anchor tag to control clicking of links in the main image on the page too.  If I remove the class="product-image" from the markup above, will that solve the problem?

Comment: that will solve this problem.  i cant say if it will create others :)

Comment: Can I hire you to solve this issue?  Can you work through GIThub?  Our developer disappeared on us.

Comment: Robert.  It may be more complicated than that as I believe that class is called by category images, and the main image on the product page so it is not clickable.  maybe that is done so the zoom tool works more seamlessly.  I will definitely send your wife a dress, that is a fair trade.  I will email you the git info.

Comment: I have added you to our github instance (7 square services - pinupgirl repository) so you can download the code and work with it.  Just let me know when you have made changes as we need to run a command to push the changes to the staging site.